# How to update wget to 1.16 on WSL?

Tags: apt, wget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently trying to use `Bazel` on my WSL installation, but I am getting the error:

> wget: unrecognized option '--show-progress'
>   Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
>
> Try `wget --help' for more options.

I have searched around, and found that the `--show-progress` option was only added in `wget=1.16`, and I only have `wget=1.15`. I am not sure how I can update to 1.16 though.

`sudo apt install wget=1.16` fails saying that

> E: Version '1.16' for 'wget' was not found

and `apt-cache policy wget` doesn't mention anything about anything past 1.15:

```
wget:
  Installed: 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.3
  Candidate: 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.15-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Does Ubuntu have support for wget 1.16? How can I install it? Thanks!

Comment: WSL Ubuntu is currently 16.04.And 16.04 has 1.17.1. Just upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: @muru Thanks for responding! I just noticed that, and am trying that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last version here : https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
tar xf wget-latest.tar.gz
rm wget-latest.tar.gz
cd wget-*
./configure
#optional: make check
make
#optional: make installcheck
make install
```